# DMV [dm_pdw_exec_requests] having NULL start_time stamp, resource class

Tags: azure-synapse

I have a SQL Procedure running on SQL DW everyday and I was trying to analyze the stats that is captured in DMV [dm_pdw_exec_requests].

My Procedure ran for 288 minutes- but when i saw in DMV table , I see it has 10 rows with few rows having null resource class and empty start_time. Is it fair to exclude all rows with NULL/empty in start_time and resource_class to find the total time elapsed ?

[image: Data from dm_pdw_exec_requests table]

Thanks,
Aravind

Answer (score 0):

If you query sys.dm_pdw_exec_requests, you should see a single entry for each batch execution. If you have a statement like this:

```
SELECT 1;
GO

SELECT 2;
GO
```

You would expect to see two rows in dm_pdw_exec_requests:

[image]

In your case, I'm assuming your procedure is the one with the command exec dbo.Proc1. You would only look for the total_elapsed_time for that statement. The other entries are other batches you have executed against your instance. We have a great write up on how to [Monitor your workload using DMVs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-manage-monitor) that will be very helpful.

Comment: Hi Matt, Thanks for the response. We are running the Stored Procedures through ADF pipeline activity and we noticed all the queries with session_id SID473037 are part of the procedure Proc1 . What is confusing to me is there are 2 rows with 288 elapsed minutes in the DMV with same session_id and different query_id. So trying to understand the pattern of logging done by SQL DW - when a procedure is executed via ADF Pipeline activities